# iphone NSDate NSDateFormatter to a ceratin format

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

i want to convert my NSDate to a certain format which is:

"Wednesday, December, 2, 2009"

does anybody know what is the corresponding format string to that date example?

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/df100103.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007972-SW1) for date formatting syntax, looks like what you need  would be @"%A, %B,%d,%Y"